# SQL Server Trigger containing one or two cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a cursor, or cursors, inside of a trigger. What I need to do is when one field in a table is updated, I have to have one cursor or two cursors iterate through and record all of the fields in a table and insert the old and new values into a table.

Here is the code I currently have. This code iterates through the new values in the inserted table correctly, but does not iterate through the old values, in the deleted table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Audit_Emp_Trigger]
   ON  [dbo].[EMPLOYEE]
   AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
--Set the fields that we will need in this trigger
DECLARE @OldLName NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @NewLName NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @OldSSN INT;
DECLARE @NewSSN INT;
DECLARE @OldDno INT;
DECLARE @NewDno INT;
DECLARE @Fname NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Mname NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @BDate DATE;
DECLARE @Address NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Sex CHAR(1);
DECLARE @Salary INT;
DECLARE @SuperSSN INT;


--Only execute the trigger if the Dno field was updated or deleted
IF UPDATE(Dno)
BEGIN
--If this is an insert operation, we will be inserting a new Dno value

SELECT @OldLName = D.LName FROM deleted D
SELECT @OldSSN = D.Ssn FROM deleted D
SELECT @OldDno = D.Dno FROM deleted D

DECLARE InsertCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Fname, Minit, Lname, Ssn, Bdate, Address, Sex, Salary, Super_ssn, Dno FROM inserted

OPEN InsertCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCursor INTO @Fname, @Mname, @NewLName, @NewSSN, @BDate, @Address, @Sex, @Salary, @SuperSSN, @NewDno

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

--If the Audit_Emp_Record table does not exist already, we need to create it
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Audit_Emp_Record') IS NULL
BEGIN
--Table does not exist in database, so create table
CREATE TABLE Audit_Emp_Record
(
date_of_change smalldatetime,
old_Lname varchar (50),
new_Lname varchar (50),
old_ssn int,
new_ssn int,
old_dno int,
new_dno int
);

--Once table is created, insert the values of the update operation into the table
INSERT INTO Audit_Emp_Record(date_of_change, old_Lname, new_Lname, old_ssn, new_ssn, old_dno, new_dno) VALUES(GETDATE(), @OldLName, @NewLName, @OldSSN, @NewSSN, @OldDno, @NewDno)

END

ELSE
BEGIN
--The table already exists, so simply insert the new values of the update operation into the table
INSERT INTO Audit_Emp_Record(date_of_change, old_Lname, new_Lname, old_ssn, new_ssn, old_dno, new_dno) VALUES(GETDATE(), @OldLName, @NewLName, @OldSSN, @NewSSN, @OldDno, @NewDno)
END

FETCH NEXT FROM InsertCursor INTO @Fname, @Mname, @NewLName, @NewSSN, @BDate, @Address, @Sex, @Salary, @SuperSSN, @NewDno

END

END

END
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If you have Enterprise, Change Data Capture may be a better solution for you than custom triggers.

Comment: ***PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE*** don't do this!! A trigger should be very lean, mean and fast - cursors are anything but that!! Don't do this, seriously - this will **kill** all performance, it's a really horribly bad approach..... A trigger should only do a very quick something - insert a row into another table or something - but a trigger should ***NOT*** do extensive processing! If you need that, have the trigger make a note into a "command" table, and have a separate scheduled job run and do those long-running processing steps...

Comment: You just need to write a single `INSERT` statement that cross-joins the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables in a `FROM` clause, based on whatever column(s) aren't subject to change and allow you to match up the rows between those two tables. Also, you really shouldn't be thinking about creating a table from within the trigger - just create the table, once, at the same time that you create the trigger.

Comment: A couple things to note - I was instructed to use a trigger so I have to.  I understand performance issues but I have to do it this way.  What would I join a SQL statement with the inserted and deleted tables with?  Could I join on any single row, or does it have to be all columns

Comment: @JonathanDurda: not saying anything against using a *trigger* - but ***please*** don't use a **cursor** inside a trigger!

Comment: @marc_s My question then becomes, how do I take the values that are being updated, contained in the inserted table, and merge them with the deleted table to write the old and new values like I need to?

Comment: You already got the answer from @Damien_The_Unbeliever - join the `Inserted` and `Deleted` tables that hold the old and new values - wherever there's a difference, an update has been made. One single, simple `SELECT` - no messy and performance-killing cursors needed at all ...